# Proper use of wp_enqeue_style

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I have the following code in my functions.php file. It works, but I am wondering if this is best practice for including styles in wordpress. Also do I need to register the style with wp_reister_style, since it works without and why do I need to do so?

```
<?php
function mrskitson_load_styles(){
if (!is_admin()){
wp_register_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}//if not admin ends
}//function mrskitson_load_styles ends
add_action('get_header', 'mrskitson_load_styles');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You only need to provide the script path *once*, *either* in the `wp_register_style()` call, *or* in the `wp_enqueue_style()` call, but not *both*. (In fact, in this context, it would be fine to omit the `wp_register_style()` call entirely, and just use the `wp_enqueue_style()` call.)
2. You're hooking into the *wrong action*. Try hooking into `wp_enqueue_scripots` instead of into `get_header`. (Note: this will require the Theme to include a call to `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the document head - but it should be doing so, anyway.)

Other considerations:

- For custom styles/scripts, I would recommend *prefixing* the style slug; e.g. change `main` to `srskitson-main`.